# Get source code of python module imported dynamically with imp

Tags: python, python-import, inspection

I need to get the source code of a class imported from a module dynamically with imp. While this is straight forward with inspect if the module was imported using classic import I am having trouble finding a way to do so when the module is dynamically imported with imp...

Comment: `python2` or `python3`?

Comment: Python 2.7 for now, someday python 3